# azure data factory web activity properties

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity, azure-authentication

I want to use a web activity to access my storage account and I want to used System Managed Idenity to authenticate but I don't know what to write in the Resource field.

Am I supposed to put the resource the data factory trying to access to, the storage, or the resource who is accessing, the data factory?

Comment: Hi MaayanY, have you checked this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#managed-identity) for managed identity authentication. You can try providing resource value as `https://management.azure.com/`

Comment: Hi NiharikaMoola-MT, thank for the response. I read the document but I didn't understand if I need to provide the data factory value or the storage value –

Comment: Have you tried using a linked service ? azure storagr linked service support managed identity.

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes I'm using linked service

Answer (score 1):

In your **storage account**,

- Add role assignment with a role as Storage Blob Data Contributor.
- Assign access to Managed identity
- Select Member and add your data factory as a member.

In Azure data factory **web activity**:

- Provide the URL of your blob as below.

  ex: https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/filename
- Method: **GET**
- Add headers

  **x-ms-version: 2017-11-09**

  **xs-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob**
- Authentication: **System Assigned Managed Identity**
- Resource: **https://storage.azure.com/**

[image]

Output:

[image]

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrMpZoh4UcY